# How to mix a character and a numerical variable in axis label of ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

Hi I have written a simple function to make a plot of a-th polynomial of x in ggplot2. Following is my code:

```
PlotPower <- function(x,a){
y <- x^a
dat <- data.frame(x,y)
f <- function(x) x^a
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + stat_function(fun = f, colour = "red") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(dat$x, n = 10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty(dat$y, n = 10)) +
                 labs(x = "x", y = expression(x^a), title = "Polynomial plot of x")
}
```

Now say I am calling PlotPower(1:10,3), the plot looks like
[image]

But I want y axis label to automatically change into x^3. I have not been able to do that. I have tried to write

```
labs(y = "x"^a)
```

but I am getting error message: Error in "x"^a : non-numeric argument to binary operator, which is expected as I am mixing a character variable with a numerical variable.

Please help me writing the ggplot2 y axis label properly inside my PlotPower function so that with whatever "a" I call the PlotPower function, I get y axis label as x^a, where x is the character x but a is the value of argument a.

Comment: For your purposes this should work: `labs(y = parse(text=paste0("x^",a)))`

Comment: Or `y = bquote(x^~.(a))` [via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005233/how-to-use-simultaneously-superscript-and-variable-in-a-axis-label-with-ggplot2).

Comment: `y = substitute(x^z, list(z=a))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestions are working.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `expression` with `bquote`. The variable inside `.(a)` is the one that gets substituted. For more variations -like the ones mentioned in the comments- look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels).

```
PlotPower <- function(x,a){
  y <- x^a
  dat <- data.frame(x,y)
  ylab = paste("x", a, sep='^')
  f <- function(x) x^a
  ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + stat_function(fun = f, colour = "red") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(dat$x, n = 10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty(dat$y, n = 10)) +
    labs(x = "x", y = bquote(x^.(a)), title = "Polynomial plot of x")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working.

Comment: @BMisra, splendid, if it is, would you mark the answer/question as answered so that this thread is closed?